# Show map view with route in PowerBI

Tags: google-maps, powerbi

I have a big dataframe with several route links from googlemaps, like below:

`https://www.google.com/maps/dir/?api=1&origin=41.1594193279733,-8.58080401684803&destination=41.1614722272002,-8.58186114728745&travelmode=driving`

I would like to show it in PowerBI, is this possible?

Answer (score -1):

A couple of ideas to try.

**Embed Google Maps in an iFrame**
You can use this custom visual: [HTML Content](https://appsource.microsoft.com/en-us/product/power-bi-visuals/WA200001930?tab=Overview) - to display an iframe within Power BI. Google however prevents Google Maps loading in an iframe. Luckily, Google does allow maps to be embedded - follow the steps needed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/quickstart#before_you_begin) first (it's free). The embed URL will be different to that you have in your dataset, however it shouldn't take much to transform what you have to what it needs.

**Power Apps in Power BI**
You can try using the Power Apps visual in Power BI. Create a new Power App with the map control, then with the Power BI integration, you should be able to pass the start/end of the route to Power Apps. See [Show A Route On A Power Apps Map](https://www.matthewdevaney.com/show-a-route-on-a-power-apps-map/).

I hope the above two inspire you to realize your ambition.

Comment: Typically all we can do is theorize on the rationale behind the downvotes.  The voter is unlikely to ever return here to even see your comment.  Taking a wild guess, in this case it might be because a few folks so far believe the question should be closed.  In that case, some folks will downvote the answers at the same time.  This often allows the Community Bot (Roomba) to delete the question faster once it is closed.  In that case, you'll get back the small amount of rep lost from the downvote anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, appreciate you taking the time to share this. Good to know.